# Printing on Windows - Multiple Child windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, printing, gdi

I have an application with a window (created offscreen) that has multiple child HWNDs in it. How do I print it?

I call PrintDdlg() and get the printing DC, fine. But how do I tell the main window to draw between the StartPage() /  EndPage() calls? It seems that I have to manually go through the children and call the draw code? Or do I send a WM_PRINT (or WM_PAINT?) message to the top level window.

I can get some things printing on the screen, but its not obvious that I am doing it right.

For instance: If I draw for a child window I usually get the child windows DC and use that. But will that work or do I need to only use the printing DC - in other words are the child window DC's smart enough to look up to the top parent and figure out that we are printing?

I guess if anyone has seen some best practices on this I would be curious to see them. All the documentation for printing I can find is for trivial examples.

This is in C++ with basically raw Win32 I am updating a decade old print loop.

Right now my solution is to manually go through the window hierarchy from back to front and tell each child window to draw. I am having issues with text scaling, origin (every child window draws at top left which I can see), and other problems. These can all be fixed manually, of course. I am now off to spend hours on seeing if implementing WM_PRINT will work. All the examples on WM_PRINT deal with getting a microscopic bit map to draw into a memory based DC. But the docs for WM_PRINT kind of lead one to think its for printing.

Comment: What language are you doing this in? Are you using a framework such as MFC?

Comment: As I edited - I am updating an old application that had printing working, but breaking. Its a C++ app, it has its own C based framework.

Comment: I do believe that if the Window isn't visible, it isn't drawn?

Comment: You should explain what worked, what doesn't work anymore, and what changes you have made. Do you use the `PrintWindow` API?

Comment: Are you using a Document-View pattern, or something similar?

Comment: The notion that the windows on the monitor are suitable for printing as well is a very questionable one.  This invariably falls apart when you start display content in scrollable windows.  And it is always ugly, every pixel turns into a 6x6 blob of ink.  And it doesn't need your help anyway, the user can simply press the Print-Screen button.  Focus on designing the way the printouts look without regard for the way your UI looks.

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches with a variety of pros and cons.

1. Send [`WM_PRINTCLIENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the window.  Not all window types support this message, but most of the standard controls do.  It's pretty easy to try it out.  One drawback is it might not scale well if the printer resolution is very different than the screen resolution.
2. Emulate a screen capture by doing a BitBlt from the DC of the window to a memory DC and then blit that to the printer DC.  This is more portable than the first approach, but you're essentially locked into the screen resolution.
3. Rework the application so that you have a data model from which you generate both the screen layout and the printer layout.  This is a lot of work, but it lets you tailor the layout to each device.

Comment: Well - this ain't no windows form app. Its OpenGL, with a abstraction layer that runs OpenGL when available and MoveTo/LineTo, etc when there is no gl. So all the screen and printer layout is 'done'.  I think that a WM_PRINT might work, but will save me little time. On the Mac side of this app, printing is 'easy' - I just get the equivalent WM_PAINT msgs and all the views can ask for scale, OpenGL, etc and draw as normal. When I issue WM_PAINT, the child windows draw to their own DC, not the printing DC. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this BEFORE I actually try it, but this may be all that I get:

In my drawing abstraction, I will go through each class, then draw that class, and just before calling my internal, custom draw method for each child window, I will call

SetViewportOrgEx (child windows location in main window)
SetViewportExtEx (child windows extent in main window)

Perhaps also ScaleViewportExtEx()

So something like:

```
HDC printDC = fromPrintDlg.dc;
void MyPaneClass::DrawForPrint(mainWindow, printDC)
{
 for (child window* chWin in main window)
 {
     Point offset = GetOffsetfromMainWindow(chWin);
     Size size = GetWindowSize(chWin);
     SetViewportOrgEx(printDC ,offset);
     SetViewportExtEx(printDC , size);
     ScaleViewportExtEx(printDC , printerPixelsPerInch/screenPPI);

     chWin->DrawSelf();
     // reccursively call, but keep main top window ref:
     chWin->DrawForPrint(mainWindow, printDC);

  }
}
```